# Arduino fingerprint Scanner stop loop after enroll or delete

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

How can I stop the loop when I enroll a fingerprint to the module?

The loop is stuck in enrolling fingerprint even it was already done. The result I want was after the enrollment of fingerprint, it will exit the loop of enrollment and start the default switch command. Thank you in advance.

Here is my loop code.

```
    void loop() {
//
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      // read the incoming byte:
      command = Serial.read();
  
      // say what you got:
      Serial.print("I received: ");
      Serial.println(command);
    }
    switch (command) {
    case 'A':
    {
      Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
      Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");
      id = readnumber();
      if (id == 0) {// ID #0 not allowed, try again!
         return;
      }
      Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
      Serial.println(id);
    
      while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
    }
      break;
    case 'B':
    {
      Serial.println("Case 2");
    }
      break;
    default:
    {
        getFingerprintDoorLoob();
        delay(50);   
    }
      break;
  }
}
```

Here is the enroll fingerprint code:

```
 uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger1.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger1.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger1.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger1.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.print(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger1.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  
  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);
  
  p = finger1.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
  
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger1.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Stored!");

  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
}
```

This was the current result, what I expect was after it was stored the loop will break. please help thank you
[image]

Comment: you have to give the `while` loop an exit status

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem here. Now observe the

`if(Serial.available>0)`

`{`

`//Block of Statements`

`}`

Your closing bracket for **that** if statement must be after the `switch()` statement.

For every iteration (`void loop()`) your `command` variable runs your switch and calls the enrolling function.

So it should be:

`if (Serial.available>0){`

`//Block of statements`

`Switch(command){`

`//Block of statements}`

`}`

`}`

Hope this helped

Comment: that result was the same, what I want was after enrollment loop then it will break but the result was after enrolling a fingerprint , the loop will start again in enrollment loop.